# log4j add prefix to all messages from one abstract class

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

I am trying to use log4j to add prefix to all log commands.

Previously I have been using @Slf4j in front of all classes, but now I need to add certain prefix to all messages, so this is no longer possible.

My class structure is as follows:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    protected final MyLogger log;
    MyAbstractClass(String foodType) {
        this.log = new MyLogger(Logger.getLogger(this.getClass(), foodType));
    }
}

class MyClass1 extends MyAbstractClass {
    MyClass1(String foodType) { super(foodType); }   
    public static void myMethod1() {
        log.info("hehe");
    } 
}

class MyClass2 extends MyAbstractClass {
    MyClass2(String foodType) { super(foodType); }   
    public static void myMethod2() {
        log.info("hohohoho");
    } 
}

/* MyLogger.java */

@Slf4j
public class MyLogger  {
    private final Logger LOGGER;
    private String PREFIX;
    public MyLogger(Logger logger, String foodType) {
        LOGGER = logger;
        PREFIX = foodType + ": ";
    }

    public void info(final String str) {
        log.info(PREFIX + str);
    }

    public void warn(final String str) {
        log.warn(PREFIX + str);
    }

    public void debug(final String str) { log.debug(PREFIX + str); }

    public void error(final String str) {
        log.error(PREFIX + str);
    }

    public void error(final String str, Exception e) {
        log.error(PREFIX + str, e);
    }
    ...

    // i know.. it's so inconvenient because I have to override all the methods that I want to use from log4j Logger. I wish there is an alternative.

}
```

If I were to do something like this,

```
public static void main() {
    MyClass1 c1 = new MyClass1("burger");
    MyClass2 c2 = new MyClass2("pizza");
    c1.myMethod1();
    c2.myMethod2();
}
```

I would get something like this.

```
/* console */
[INFO] MyLogger#info - burger: hehe
[INFO] MyLogger#info - pizza: hohoho
```

BUT, i would like to get something like this to be able to trace where exactly it came from (original Log4j does this).

```
/* console */
[INFO] MyClass1#MyMethod1 - burger: hehe
[INFO] MyClass2#MyMethod2 - pizza: hohoho
```

Is there way for me to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Rathan that wrapping the the `log4j` logger, why don't you do something like `log.info(foodType + ": hehe"  )`? Also, I don't see where the `#info` is generated for `[INFO] MyLogger#info`. Is it defined in a `PatternLayout`? If so, post that too.

Comment: @bradimus I could do the log.info(food type + ":" + msg) method, but this is very repetitive when I have many log calls. I just wanted a more clean way to do this haha. Also, I am not aware of PatternLayout, could you give some more info on this?. #info is generated because the log4j log calls are made from MyLogger.info. log4j seem to be tracking its log calls to the MyLogger functions rather than the actual methods that call the log functions (MyClass1.myMethod1 and MyClass2.myMethod2)

Comment: [`PattenLayout` javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).

Comment: @bradimus here is the full pattern layout (i revised a bit and still cant get burger and pizza to print): %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%-5p] %c{1}#%M - %m%n

Comment: problem solved? With the pattern above, I got the correct output.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38159124/65839

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using the MDC Pattern. I no longer need MyLogger class. I can just use the Log4j 's Logger class.

You can do something like

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    protected final Logger log;
    MyAbstractClass(String foodType) {
        MDC.put("myfood", foodType);
        this.log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()));
    }
}
```

and in the pattern, you can add on %X{myfood} to access the variables you set :)

More on MDC here: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [`PatternLayout`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) (and you should) you can do this by defining the pattern to be

```
%C{1}:%M - %m%n
```

Comment: Could you please extend on this? I am not very aware of PatternLayout

Comment: @Blee here is a nice tutorial on layouts. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

Comment: this doesnt work. still prints MyLogger#info.
Here is the pattern i made: %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%-5p] %c{1}#%M - %m%n

Comment: I should also add that I want to be able to control Logging level for individual classes in XML. Currently, in my log4j.xml, I just have this:`<logger name="com.logger.MyLogger">
        <level value="INFO" />
    </logger>`
And I have no control on individual classes (MyClass1, MyClass2)

Comment: @Blee It's a **capital `C`** in your pattern is a small `c`